# Sending Goal to action server fails

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, motion-planners

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to send goals to the move_base action server, as per
 [the ROS tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals) . My action server is the one created by  `roslaunch move_base_amcl_2.5cm.launch`  from the navigation_stage package.

I *always* get the server error "Failed to find a valid control". This is also the case no matter what launch file I use from the navigation_stage package. I desperately want  one single test case (no matter how simple) for which the base_local_planner is used to find the goal.

In addition, setting the initialpose from the command line hangs; the message is latched, but there is no effect in Stage.

FYI, my ros version is 1.2.4 and I use cturtle. As I have other packages working fine in this environment, I don't want to upgrade to diamondback and the newest nav stack unless there is no option.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10396/sending-goal-to-action-server-fails/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2011-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I resolved the problem by installing diamondback with Boost 1.40.0. The boost threads I had was causing multiple issues, including crashing stage-ros frequently. Thanks, Eitan.

---

Originally posted by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) with karma: 365 on 2011-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0